# Magento 2: How to move go to check out button to bottom of the page in summary section?

Tags: magento2, checkout-page

In the checkout page, I'm trying to move go to check out button to the bottom of the summary section (after order totals) in `checkout_cart_index.xml` layout but it's not working, is there any solution.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add your block after checkout cart totals block with tag after as shown screen shoot

[image]